# How can I find the oldest ticket that is not closed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
Ticket #      SubmitDate    Status
    101        1/1/2015     Closed
    102        1/1/2015     Closed
    103        1/1/2015     Closed
    104        1/2/2015      Open
    105        1/2/2015     Closed
    106        1/2/2015      Open
    107        1/2/2015      Open
    108        1/2/2015     Closed
    109        1/3/2015     Closed
    110        1/4/2015      Open
    111        1/5/2015     Closed
    112        1/5/2015     Closed
    113        1/5/2015      Open
    114        1/5/2015      Open
    115        1/5/2015      Open
```

I'm trying to find the oldest ticket that is still open.
I know that MIN(SubmitDate) will get the me oldest SubmitDate but I'm having trouble putting the query together.

NEW EDIT:
Hi again all.  I am revising the question so it is more clear.  I apologize to anyone that thought it was confusing.  I was under pressure to get an answer right away so I posted it too hastily.

I am trying to determine the oldest ticket # that is still in 'Open' status.
I've being going about it all wrong:

Here is one of my failed queries:

```
SELECT

MIN(SubmitDate) as [Date Submitted]
,(SELECT FROM TicketTable WHERE Status = 'Open' AND SubmitDate = MIN(SubmitDate)) as [Ticket #]
,Status as [Status]

FROM TicketTable
```

The result I am trying to achieve is:

```
Date Submitted  Ticket #    Status
1/2/2015          104        Open
```

Again, I apologize profusely.   It was never my intention to simply get the answer.  I was merely hoping for a hint.  Thanks again all.

Comment: SELECT MIN(Date) FROM Table WHERE Status='Open'

Comment: @JonH That only gets you the date, not the other requested columns

Comment: It's also not an answer..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there didn't seem to be any real effort in trying to solve this. I don't feel referencing `MIN(SubmitDate)` constituted a genuine effort to find a solution. Showing us some of the failed query attempts would have made me feel differently.

Comment: Sorry, but i was in a rush.  I didn't include any of my failed queries because i didn't think it would be helpful.  And I sorta guessed that this would be a simple query.  Thanks for your input regardless.

Comment: It would be helpful for us to gauge that a genuine attempt was made. To me this almost seemed like a homework assignment that bordered on _Gimme the Codez_. Others may disagree on the interpretation of genuine effort since it is subjective, and I do respect that.

Comment: @jmoerdyk - that is like abusing group by to get correct data just because someone doesn't know how to use aggregates and group by.  What's stopping you from getting the other fields, I'd advise learning basic SQL to use min and some additional sql to get the additional columns, come on guys this is pretty basic knowledge.  My point is you can use aggregates to get that record, in this case you'd have the id you needed, so write additional sql to get a comp. query..etc.

Comment: I fully understand that we need to to our best research and make every effort to figure out the code on our own.  I did spend a couple of days trying to.  I am still very much a newb when it comes to SQL.  I was just hoping to get a hint.  Sorry to have wasted anyone's time.  I certainly do appreciate everyone's input.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
select top 1 * from table
where "status" = 'Open'
order by "SubmitDate" asc ;
```

In SQL Server 2012+ versions, you can also use the (standard) `offset - fetch` syntax, replacing `top`:

```
select * from table
where "status" = 'Open'
order by "SubmitDate" asc 
offset 0 rows
fetch first 1 row only ;
```

Comment: Why don't you just use MIN ?

Comment: @JonH How could you use `MIN` and get the required results simpler than this query?

Comment: This is the simplest way to do it!

Comment: very simple answer. No need to use MIN

Comment: @Lamak - I don't know to me I hate seeing top if I can execute a query and get exactly what I want considering we have..well you know aggregates.

Comment: @JonH So, you hate to use `TOP`  even if using `MIN` would require a more complex and likely slower query?

Comment: @jonh, the required results contained all of the fields of the table. `TOP 1` is the simplest way to get that since it doesn't require a subquery.

Comment: when it comes to performance, I want to get rid of every aggregate if possible.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote a perfectly valid answer?  Just because it's not your preferred way of doing things doesn't make this answer bad or unuseful.

Comment: Wow so simple. Congratz in reaching 1000

Comment: Thanks STB and everyone else that offered help.  You all are so fast!!  I apologize if this question appeared to show no research effort.  That is not the case.  I have searched (all the wrong places including here) for the past couple of days..  I always try first to find the answer on my own but I really needed an answer so I posted here.  Again, thanks everyone! =D

Comment: @Sung note that if you have multiple tickets with the same (latest) submitDate, this query will only return one of them. If you want all of the tickets in that scenario, you need to add `WITH TIES`.

Comment: @Aaron - Yes, there will be multiple tickets with the same submit date.   I don't know what "WITH TIES" is, but I will be sure to look it up.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something (since no one appears to have noticed this so far) but I have to ask: shouldn't the sorting be in the ascending order?

Comment: @AndriyM Yes, you are right, I am not sure where everyone (myself included) derived the idea that this was about the "latest"open  ticket.

Comment: @Sung This is [why we have documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

```
select top 1 * from Table where Status = 'Open' order by SubmitDate desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `row_number()` with an `order by` clause on `SubmitDate` will do the trick.

```
select SubmitDate, [Ticket #], Status
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over (order by SubmitDate) as rn
          from mytable t
         where t.Status = 'Open') x
 where x.rn = 1
```

Comment: Lots of unneccessary SQL here. It gets the job done but is pretty ineffective way of doing things...Why subquery? Why are you selecting * from a subquery? Wouldn't the whole point of the subquery be to hide the RN?

Comment: @Hituptony: Because `stb`'s excellent answer didn't come to mind when I wrote this :)

Comment: I like it. It's not the "Best" answer since you can't beat `SELECT TOP 1...` for this question, but it's a way to solve it that might help someone out in the future, in the event that a Min(Date) is needed for each status...

Comment: Much better! @sstan Good job!

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen, most of your answers are of this format. I personally think this is the most strait forward and reads as it says w/o confusing nested queries and using mins.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM 
    YourTable 
WHERE 
    Status = 'Open'
ORDER BY
    SubmitDate Desc
```

Answer (score -1):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/81170/1)**

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable Y,
    (SELECT  MIN(SubmitDate) mDate
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Status = 'Open') as T
WHERE Y.SubmitDate = T.mDate
  AND Status = 'Open'
```

Comment: @Hituptony Yes, i saw now there is better way of do it. But that was the first one I tought :(

Comment: This query could return wrong results if the oldest open ticket has the same date as a closed ticket.

Comment: @sstan I fix it again. Now is even more complex :( not my best compare with the top answer. The only thing is mine return the ties .

Answer (score -1):

I just have to add another one to the already great list:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE submitDate IN (SELECT min(SubmitDate) FROM table WHERE status = 'Open')
```

Personally, though, I would go with @STB's with the `SELECT TOP 1...` route, as that will most likely be the best performing of the group. The rest will rely on subqueries which means hitting the table twice by the DB (including this one).

But... just wanted to share that there are many ways to go about it

Comment: Note that your results can differ from the TOP 1 approach because it doesn't use WITH TIES - so the other answers will always get exactly one row, whereas yours could return multiple rows with the same submitDate.

Comment: Actually, this query could return wrong results if the oldest open ticket has the same date as a closed ticket.

Comment: @sstan Oh true, I missed that part

Comment: That's true. I was thinking that when I wrote it; however, given the data in the table, it will work fine. This has been a fun question. :)

Comment: @JNevill "given the data in the table" - so you assume that the OP really only has 15 rows, and is now read-only?

Comment: Yep. That's what I thought. Is that not the case?

Comment: Tables very rarely become read only, and it is also very rarely practical for an OP to dump their ***entire table*** into a question.